# PrimeNG: 'p-table' is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm working on an Angular 6 application and I need to create a toggle table with PrimeNG 7.0.5, but I've got this problem when I tried to use `<p-table>`:

> 'p-table' is not a known element

Same problem when I want to use parameters as 'value' in < p-table >.

I am using the Documentation of the TurboTable [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table).

I have imported the TableModule in my app.module.ts.

app.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule, registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgModule, Pipe, PipeTransform, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MessageComponent } from './message/message.component';
import { MessageService } from './message/message.service';
// imported it here
import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';

registerLocaleData(localeFr);

export const createTranslateLoader = (http: HttpClient) => {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        TableModule,    /* <-- added this */
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
                deps: [HttpClient]

            }
        }),
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, MessageComponent],
    providers: [AuthGuard, MessageService, { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr-FR' }],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

For the html, I've just tested the code with this:

```
<p-table></p-table>
```

I found nothing about this case on the net and on this version...
Has somebody has ever had this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you did 'wrong'. Check out this working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9qwaeg)

Comment: Import it in the module where your component class belongs to.

Comment: I verify, i've just declared it in the AppModule

Answer (score 13, accepted):

import { TableModule } in the module in which component you are using it

Comment: There is no space in the code, i've just had it into the post because p-table disappeared without space :/

Comment: It was that, i didn't imported the module in the good file. Thank you !

Answer (score 8):

First, please make sure you are generating angular and installing primeNG of the compatible version. I also got the same problem before I update my node.js. My node version is now. V12.16.2 and when I install primeNG I got a compatible version.
So in part of my package.json is as follows:

```
"@angular/common": "9.0.4",
"@angular/compiler": "9.0.4",
"@angular/core": "9.0.4",
```

And the primeNG installed is of the following version:

```
"primeicons": "^2.0.0",
"primeng": "^9.0.5",
```

Then, importing the module should be in the nearest module to the html file.

```
import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

Even after adding the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to my module and ensuring version compatibility, I was not able to get rid of the error. I looked further at the error message:

```
Error: src/app/my.component/my.component.html:3:1 - error NG8001: 'p-table' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-table' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

And was able to figure the cause:
`MyComponent` was using the PrimeNG table, and that it was not declared in the App Module. So all I had to do was add the `MyComponent` in declarations array for the module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    TableModule
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```