# <PrimeNG component> is not a known element even when imported

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I'm trying to use the table component from the PrimeNG library in order to create a list of users.
Even though the Table module is declared in the module "closest" to my component, I get the `NG8001: 'p-table' component is not a known element` error.
I'm also using tailwind for CSS.

I already tried to declare the table module in the other modules I have in my app in case I made something wrong about this part but in vain.
This makes me think it might be a lower level issue

Here is some code of my module :

```
import {TableModule} from "primeng/table";
// Other imports

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UsersComponent, // My component
  ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TableModule,
    ]
})
export class AdminDashboardModule { }
```

users.component.html :

```
<h1>Active users</h1>
<div class="border-b border-gray-200 shadow w-full">
  <p-table [value]="users">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <!-- Other headers -->
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-user>
      <tr>
        <td>{{user.username }}</td>
        <!-- Other values -->
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
</div>
```

users.component.ts :

```
// Imports

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  public users: User[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Call to userService supplying users variable 
  }

}
```

Comment: It's possible that you have a versions mismatch. Check the answer, please:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61253575/8861977

Comment: @Tonnio Thanks for your answer. I have angular 12.0.5 and PrimeNG 12.0.0 installed. I try upgrading PrimeNG to 12.1.0 but still get the error

Comment: Make sure your `app.module` imports `AdminDashboardModule`.

Comment: @Patrick as I said in the topic, I already tried to import the TableModule in the different modules I have but it didn't solve the error.

Comment: @Lenr Not the `TableModule`, the `AdminDashboardModule`.  Make sure that is being brought in somewhere ... as in `app.module`.